# Extracting feeds and items deleted from RssDemon in 4.0.0 update

Tags: data-recovery, podcast, rss, rssdemon

So, in [RssDemon's 4.0.0 update](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meecel.feedreader.RssDemonAd&hl=en) they deleted all user feeds, saved items, etc. Many users are naturally very unhappy about this.

It seems possible that the old data is still on the phone, if one knows where to look. A guide to recovering the data and feeding it into a podcast/RSS app (maybe [a new one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/podcast-player-for-android)) would be fantastic.

Comment: Huh? I would have suffered this - but I dropped RssDemon a few months ago. Sorry RssDemon, I just don't read feeds on my portables anymore. But before that, I periodically saved a Feed backup, which would have been sightly out of date, but probably useable. I know I used it to build out my desktop feed reader.